# python pygubu tkinter text scrollbar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm not very new to python, but never created a GUI.

Need to create a very simple GUI for some scraper.
Used this constructor https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu to make a xml-based GUI markup.

Problem:
**Scrollbar for the textbox appear but never work.** Tried pretty much of tutorials, read docs, it seems to me that i'm doing all right (setting `yscrollcommand` property for text field and `command` for scrollbar).

**mainWindow.ui file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<interface>
  <object class="ttk.Frame" id="mainWindow">
    <property name="height">200</property>
    <property name="width">200</property>
    <layout>
      <property name="column">0</property>
      <property name="propagate">True</property>
      <property name="row">0</property>
    </layout>
    <child>
      <object class="ttk.Label" id="lblKey">
        <property name="padding">0</property>
        <property name="text" translatable="yes">Keyword:</property>
        <property name="underline">0</property>
        <layout>
          <property name="column">0</property>
          <property name="padx">5</property>
          <property name="pady">8</property>
          <property name="propagate">True</property>
          <property name="row">0</property>
          <property name="sticky">nw</property>
        </layout>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="ttk.Entry" id="input_keyword">
        <property name="text" translatable="yes">Input Keyword</property>
        <property name="width">50</property>
        <layout>
          <property name="column">1</property>
          <property name="pady">7</property>
          <property name="propagate">True</property>
          <property name="row">0</property>
          <property name="sticky">n</property>
        </layout>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="ttk.Button" id="btnStart">
        <property name="text" translatable="yes">Search</property>
        <layout>
          <property name="column">2</property>
          <property name="padx">5</property>
          <property name="pady">5</property>
          <property name="propagate">True</property>
          <property name="row">0</property>
          <property name="sticky">ne</property>
        </layout>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="tk.Text" id="logBox">
        <property name="height">10</property>
        <property name="text" translatable="yes">Logs:</property>
        <property name="width">50</property>
        <property name="yscrollcommand">yscrollbar.set</property>
        <layout>
          <property name="column">0</property>
          <property name="columnspan">3</property>
          <property name="padx">5</property>
          <property name="pady">5</property>
          <property name="propagate">True</property>
          <property name="row">1</property>
          <property name="rowspan">1</property>
          <property name="sticky">ew</property>
        </layout>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="ttk.Scrollbar" id="yscrollbar">
        <property name="command">logBox.yview</property>
        <property name="orient">vertical</property>
        <layout>
          <property name="column">2</property>
          <property name="padx">5</property>
          <property name="pady">5</property>
          <property name="propagate">True</property>
          <property name="row">1</property>
          <property name="sticky">nse</property>
        </layout>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

**related python code:**

```
class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file('mainWindow.ui')

        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('mainWindow', master)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: create GUI manually in code - you will have better control.

Answer (score 2):

I set it manually and it works.

With scrollbar is this problem, that you have to first create scrollbar and widget, and after that you can assign one to another.

You can't assign scrollbar to widget when you create widget and scrollbar doesn't exist yet. And you can't assign widget to scrollbar when you create scrollbar and widget doesn't exist yet. So you have to first create one object without assigning to second object. Next you can create second object with assigning to first object. And after that you can assign first object to second object. It can be more readable to create first both objects and after that assign one to another.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygubu

class Application:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file('mainwindow.ui')

        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('mainWindow', master)

        # get objects
        self.logBox = builder.get_object('logBox', master)
        self.yscrollbar = builder.get_object('yscrollbar', master)

        # assign scrollbar to text widget
        #<property name="yscrollcommand">yscrollbar.set</property>
        #<property name="command">logBox.yview</property>

        self.logBox['yscrollcommand'] = self.yscrollbar.set
        self.yscrollbar['command'] = self.logBox.yview

        # set some text for test
        for x in range(20):
            self.logBox.insert('end', '\nHello World!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

if the main object class of the interface in the .ui file is  tk.Toplevel
it is possible to declare the **init** method of the class Application like that:

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
```

And then:

```
if __name__== '__main__':
    app = Application()
```